# Search ids in comma separated string with an input comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the table **tasks**

```
id | assigned_to | viewers
1    100           100,200,300
2    200           125,200,310
3    300           175,250,300
4    400           400,440,670
5    500           500,111,333
```

I will get an input string that may contain more than 1000 comma separated values, like

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,,,100,,,,500,,,,1000
```

I want to get all the rows from the table that are matching to "**assigned_to**" or "**viewers**" from the input string. I have tried with **IN()** for "**assigned_to**",

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE assign_to IN ($inputString)
```

but then couldn't get any solution to match with "**viewers**" column.

Is there any way to match a comma separated string with another comma separated string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: NORMALIZE your database

Comment: this task would be a lot easier if you could refactor your database structure: having `multiple values in one column of one row` in a `relational database` is generally considered bad practice; `viewers` should really be in a separate table and referenced only via foreign key; that would introduce a new table `TaskViewers` that only has two columns `TaskId` and `ViewerId` you can then join that table against that tasks table like `SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks INNER JOIN taskviewers ON tasks.id = taskviewers.taskid WHERE tasks.assign_to IN ($inputString) OR taskviewers.viewerid IN ($inputString)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
To create a new table is possible, but then want to modify the code in lot of places. Yeah, once that is done headache is over.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: I have tried with FIND_IN_SET(), and I may need to loop through the input string of each value and there by query length will be more than 1000 lines. Still am checking for better solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE assign_to IN ($inputString) ";
$values = explode(",",$inputString);
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $str .= "AND viewers LIKE ".$val; //Replace AND with OR as per your requirement (Match all/ match any)
}

//execute query
```

This is not very efficient but would do the task.